# Android Semaphores to stop a thread

Tags: android, semaphore

I'm trying to use semaphores to make a thread waiting for something happening outside it with a semaphore, but I don't know why it is not working. Probably is something I don't know about Android semaphores, because I already used the same "way to operate" with some real time operating system (such as FreeRTOS and MXLite) and it works fine.

Practically I have a thread that is running a service each time it executes a while loop inside its run() method. The service execute some long operation and then die, I just want the thread not to run a new service before the previous one has finisched.

The code looks like that (condLog is just a function that doeas a Log.i with the string passed if a DEBUG define is true):

```
 public Handler handler = new Handler() {
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         super.handleMessage(msg);
         startScheduler(msg);
     }
 };

 private static boolean serviceRunning = false;
 private static Context context; // context is set in the main class contructor
 private executeScheduledAction myThread = new executeScheduledAction();

 private void startScheduler(Message msg) {
    condLog("startScheduler- message received...");
    myThread .releaseSemaphore();
 }

 private final class executeScheduledAction extends Thread {
    private final static int MAX_CONCURRENT = 1;
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT, true);
    public executeScheduledAction () {}
    public void releaseSemaphore() {
        semaphore.release();
        condLog("releaseSemaphore - Semaphore released, semaphore permit: " + semaphore.availablePermits());
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        condLog( "executeScheduledAction - thread started...");
        serviceRunning = true;
        while(serviceRunning ){
            try {
                condLog( "executeScheduledAction - taking semaphore, semaphore permits: " + semaphore.availablePermits() );
                semaphore.acquire(); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            condLog("executeScheduledAction - semaphore taken, running service");
            // HERE RUN THE SERVICE
        }
        condLog( "Thread finished...");
    }
}
```

THe first call myThread.start method. As I expected, the semaphore is taken the first time and the service is correctly launched. At the end, service send a message to an handler that call executeScheduledAction.release...and this is what I obtain in the Logcat:

executeScheduledAction - thread started...

executeScheduledAction - taking semaphore, semaphore permits: 1

executeScheduledAction - semaphore taken, running service

executeScheduledAction - taking semaphore, semaphore permits: 0

startScheduler - message received...

releaseSemaphore - Semaphore released, semaphore permit: 2

Why is it 2 and not 1? it looks like I'm not release the same semaphore I'm acquiring...

Really, any help would be helpfull and appreciated.

Thank you all very much
Cristiano

Answer (score 0):

`Semaphore` has to go negative to be blocking. In this case you can use  a `CountDownLatch`. If I have not misunderstood you, it should suit better your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't think this is the problem. As you can see in the LogCat row "...taking semaphore, semaphore permits: 0", the semaphore blocks when permits are at "0" (ok, and after the acquire they go to -1). The problem is that the semaphore is blocked with permits 0, but when I release I read permits = 2 that is what I cannot understand. Furthermore, the Thread execution does not start when I release, and that create the idea that the I'm not releasing the same semaphore I'm aquiring, I don't know why. Btw, I'll have a look on CountDownLatch, to be sure, thank you.